# HP 15-r212nl Ubuntu 14.04 bluetooth don't find device

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, hp

on my notebook the Bluetooth doesn't work, I can't find it with my phone even if the Bluetooth on the notebook is turned on.

**lsusb** output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg (?)

```
bluetooth 391136 22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm [   15.554813]
rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin [    2.984593]
usb 2-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio  [   15.228764] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17 [   15.228798]
Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized [15.228804]
Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized [   15.228807] Bluetooth: L2CAP-socket layer initialized [   15.228813]
Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized [   20.912079]
Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized [   20.912088]
Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized [   20.912094]
Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11 [   20.960137]
Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 [   20.960140]
Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast [   20.960148]
Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
cd ~
git clone -b troy https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt.git
cd rtl8723au_bt-troy
make 
sudo make install
```

Reboot

If updates install a new kernel, your bluetooth may fail if the new kernel doesn't support your device yet.  When that happens

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make clean
make
sudo make install
cd ~/rtl8723au_bt-troy
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Then reboot